# Error while accessing 'X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN': property doesn't exist

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to bind a graphToken in a http azure function like so:

//function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
     {
      "type": "token",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "graphToken",
      "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      "identity": "userFromRequest"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

The function itself in run.csx:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, string graphToken, TraceWriter log)
{
    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(graphToken);
}
```

When attempting to do a GET request on the function I get an exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: Error while accessing 'X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN': property doesn't exist.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.Path.BindingTemplateToken+ExpressionToken.Evaluate(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> bindingData) in BindingTemplateToken.cs, line 198

InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter 'graphToken'
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DelayedException.Throw() in DelayedException.cs, line 27

FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp1
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

The function itself is secured using Azure AD B2C and when called the users id_token is passed in as a bearer authorization.

From my understanding there are some features not supported by B2C that is supported by Azure AD - is this one of them?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you're trying to achieve here.  What is over arching goal?  Pass in a token to an Azure Function that calls the Graph API w/ that token?

Answer (score 2):

What is almost certainly going on here is that no authentication has actually occurred, so there is no token for the application to grab. We should definitely have a better error message in this case.

There are two easy ways around this:

1. Go to the relative https://*your-function-app*.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad to be prompted to login before using the API. Now if you visit the API, it will work as expected.
2. Go to Platform Features > Authentication / Authorization, and select “Log in with Azure Active Directory” from the drop down titled “Action to take when request is not authenticated”. This will automatically redirect any unauthenticated users to the AAD login flow, and once they complete the flow, the API request will return as expected.